# Detecting the probability distribution in dataset

Tags: distributions

I have a dataset in a [CSV file](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/hc915wqe3bez9om/AACv6qSKBp5CbTF8KMiukfn7a?dl=0) which is a single column of positive integers. I would like to know which probability distribution it fits.

The histogram is as follows.

[image]

This is how I am trying.

```
w = Transpose[Import["dataset.csv"]][[1]];
h = DistributionFitTest[w, SkewNormalDistribution[12, 7, 0.1], "HypothesisTestData"];
Show[Histogram[w, Automatic, "ProbabilityDensity"], 
 Plot[PDF[h["FittedDistribution"], x], {x, 0, 80}, 
  PlotStyle -> Thick]]
```

The output is:

[image]

Can I claim that my dataset has a skewed normal distribution?

Answer (score 12):

This is an extended comment to echo @MarcoB 's comment that this question would be better served on Cross Validated.

Your data consists of only even integers that range from 0 to 72.  While you can probably find a discrete probability distribution that will produce similar observed histograms (like maybe twice a negative binomial), the repeatable patterns in the sequence of observations negates being able to talk about your data as if it was a random sample from such a distribution.

Here is a plot of the observations in sequence:

[image: Data in sequence]

Consideration of how the data is generated can be even more important that just providing a compact summary/approximation of the observed histogram.

Comment: @Jim, what is the systematic way to find distribution in these scenarios?

Comment: @JimB Yeah, well, isn't that a fact...(+1).